# str_replace not working

Tags: php

I want to delete all occurrences of this substring from my html file:

```
<span style="font-size: 12pt;">BLANK PAGE</span>
```

I tried str_replace, thinking that would be a simple solution, but it does not work:

```
$html = str_replace('<span style="font-size: 12pt;">BLANK PAGE</span>', '', $html);
```

Any suggestions?

UPDATE:  Mystery solved!  Thanks to everyone for letting me know that this *should* work.  Turns out the problem had nothing to do with str_replace!  I had grabbed the html string from firebug, not realizing that firebug inserts spaces to "prettify" the html.  That's why str_replace failed to find this exact pattern.
I would ideally like to delete this question,  since the problem ended up having nothing to do with str_replace.  Is that possible?

Comment: It does work (see [here](http://ideone.com/tayIU)). Can you please post a [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html)?

Comment: I assume this HTML is then being written back to the original file?

Comment: @Doug:  Yes, I am writing the HTML back to the original file.

Comment: @Howard:  Very interesting.  I see that in your $html, you escaped the double-quotes:  $html = "ABC\n<span style=\"font-size: 12pt;\">BLANK PAGE</span>DEF\nGHI";
In my original $html, the double-quotes are not escaped.  Might that be the problem?

Answer (score 21):

`str_replace()` returns the new version - you need to assign it back to the variable (or a new variable):

```
$myhtml = str_replace('<span style="font-size: 12pt;">BLANK PAGE</span>', '', $myhtml);
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer.  Yes, that is what I tried.  I will now clarify the original post.

Answer (score 7):

It should work that way. Did you perhaps forget to assign the result back to your variable?

```
$myhtml = str_replace('<span style="font-size: 12pt;">BLANK PAGE</span>', '', $myhtml);
```

Answer (score 0):

my problem was that i was using de str_replace to replace special characters like (á,é,í,ó,ú) and it did not work . the i tried using notepad++ an change the file enconding to utf8-without BOM , uploaded the file to the server and it worked!

Answer (score -2):

you cannot replace the html tags using str_replace. It replaces the exact occurances only. If you want replace the span text "strip_tags" to remove all the tags and change span text using str_replace.

Comment: What's inexact about HTML tags?